# how to crash linux kernel

Tags: linux, kernel, crash

how to crash linux kernel without root access of personal system ?
i have to crash my linux kernel without fork bomb and without sudo or root access. please help me. 
I am searching on it from 3 weeks.

Comment: Making software crash can be fun, and (as long as the software is running on your own system) is harmless enough. If that's all you're doing, then there is nothing further to explain. However, out of curiosity, may I ask, had you a more serious purpose in mind?

Answer (score 2):

The glib answer here would be to say that you don't -- things like being able to crash the kernel from user space, or escalate privileges to the point where you have root access, are generally considered serious to critical security bugs and tend to be closed within days after they're first discovered.

More broadly, attempting to crash a system that you don't own - as evidenced by your lack of root rights to it - is quite possibly against this site's policy so I'm not sure I should give you even this much advice, but here goes:

1. Determine the exact version number (with third party patches) of the kernel the system is running on.
2. Search sites like securityfocus for CVEs pertaining the linux kernel, then look for code violation or privilege escalation vulnerabilities that were patched in versions *later* than that number, but confirmed to exist in the kernel the system *is* running.
3. Study the nature of the vulnerability, then write some code that exploits it and/or takes advantage of the circumstances described.
4. Generate the required circumstances and run the code.

This is as far as I'll help you. Don't bother asking for further help; if you can't figure out how to do any of the above, you shouldn't have been asking the original question to begin with. Good luck.